# Via Powershell Cannot Format Disk with File System NTFS?

Tags: powershell

Via Powershell Cannot Format Disk with File System NTFS?

The following code works up until the format attempt.  The script is run as administrator.  Not the file system is NTFS.  The block size is the default for the disk and NTFS.  I consistently get access denied at format attempt.  The environment is Windows 11 fully patched/updated as the date of this post.

```
    Clear-Disk -Number 6 -RemoveData -Confirm:$false
    Initialize-Disk -Number 6 -PartitionStyle GPT -Confirm:$false
    New-Partition -DiskNumber 6 -UseMaximumSize -DriveLetter 'T'
    Format-Volume -DriveLetter 'T' -FileSystem NTFS -NewFileSystemLabel 'Test' -AllocationUnitSize 4096
```

Example...

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Clear-Disk -Number 6 -RemoveData -Confirm:$false
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Initialize-Disk -Number 6 -PartitionStyle GPT -Confirm:$false
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> New-Partition -DiskNumber 6 -UseMaximumSize -DriveLetter 'T'
   DiskPath: \\?\usbstor#disk&ven_hitachi_&prod_dk23aa-60&rev_0000#000000000000&0#{53f56307-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}
PartitionNumber  DriveLetter Offset                                                                                                                 Size Type                                                                                                            
---------------  ----------- ------                                                                                                                 ---- ----                                                                                                            
2                T           16777216                                                                                                            5.58 GB Basic                                                                                                           


PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Format-Volume -DriveLetter 'T' -FileSystem NTFS -NewFileSystemLabel 'Test' -AllocationUnitSize 4096
Format-Volume : Access Denied
Activity ID: {adc29ae6-3193-0002-4318-dbb09331d901}
At line:1 char:1
+ Format-Volume -DriveLetter 'T' -FileSystem NTFS -NewFileSystemLabel ' ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (StorageWMI:ROOT/Microsoft/...age/MSFT_Volume) [Format-Volume], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StorageWMI 40001,Format-Volume
```

If I change the file system to say FAT32, the format command works.  This makes no sense to me.  When the script is run as administrator.

Example using other file system...

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Format-Volume -DriveLetter 'T' -FileSystem FAT32 -NewFileSystemLabel 'Test' -AllocationUnitSize 4096

DriveLetter FriendlyName FileSystemType DriveType HealthStatus OperationalStatus SizeRemaining    Size
----------- ------------ -------------- --------- ------------ ----------------- -------------    ----
T           TEST         FAT32          Fixed     Healthy      OK                      5.57 GB 5.57 GB
```

If I the exact same steps via the UI or Command prompt say via `diskpart`, no error.  Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: Likely means the "T" drive is not using default system top level permissions like the "C" drive for the Windows core "C" partition. When it's NTFS, right click on the "T" root in Windows Explorer, Properties, and check the security and compare to "C" drive partition security permissions. Maybe you just need to give `SYSTEM` or `nt authority\system` full access to it or something like that. If you are formatting it, then that may be worth a shot.  Here's example post but see if that's what's up, compare with "C" too at the top "T" level with the top "C" level.

Comment: This post: https://www.easeus.com/computer-instruction/external-hard-drive-access-denied.html

Comment: Try using `Format-Volume` with the `-Full` switch.

Comment: I tried full at one point.  I had already tried talking full ownership and reset permissions for entire disk, that did not resolve the issue, was the very first thing I thought of.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this turned out to be pretty twisted scenario.  After some extensive testing.  I actually got the UI (Disk Manager) to Explorer (File Manager) to replicate the denied access errors.  It seemed that PowerShell is able to trigger the issue faster and easier.  Some process was trying to take exclusive control of the disk in question in the background.  So, I disabled Defender, MalwareBytes, all backup applications, and even made sure no restore point capture process was running, and the access denied issue disappeared at some point.  The only thing I did not try was a full reboot.

Previously, I had take complete control of the disk in question, or so I thought, completely replaced all security permissions, taking full ownership, etc., in testing, but still had the access denied issue.  I still need to track down the specific process that was taking exclusive control of the disk.  But at least it seems to be an environment issue not a code issue with Powershell or the Storage module.

I did find one other odd issue, some USB based storage, Initialize-Disk fails against, with an '...already initialized...' error.  This is documented in various locations.  However the typical recommended fix of using doing a reset, via Reset-PhysicalDisk does not seem to work under Windows 11 consistently, for some USB storage devices.  Seems some USB storage devices just don't behave the same, no surprise I guess.

What does seem to work, at least with the 15 odd USB storage devices I have, and various makes and models of SSD and HDD devices, connected via eSATA, SATA, etc., is the following:

```
    #
    Clear-Disk -Number $theNumber -RemoveData -Confirm:$false

    # Documentation Suggests Reset, However Seems To Do Nothing On Some USB Storage Types...
    Reset-PhysicalDisk -FriendlyName (Get-PhysicalDisk -DeviceNumber $theNumber).FriendlyName 

    # Initalize-Disk Fails On Some USB Storage Types, Returns Initialization Is Already Complete...
    Initialize-Disk -Number $theNumber -PartitionStyle GPT -Confirm:$false -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    #
    New-Partition -DiskNumber $theNumber -UseMaximumSize -DriveLetter $theDrive | Out-Null

    #
    Format-Volume -DriveLetter $theDrive -FileSystem $theFileSystem -NewFileSystemLabel $theVolume -AllocationUnitSize $theSize -Force | Out-Null
```

Using the silentlycontinue option is a bit of a hack, but I have yet to find a way to test if a given disk is initialized but not yet formatted.  Test for 'RAW' is insufficient.  You can have a disk under the right circumstances, online but uninitialized, i.e. not RAW.

If anyone has a PowerShell code snippet to test explicitly for a disk that is in this quasi initialized but not in a RAW state, might be worth sharing here.